# corodva file read executing both success and failure callbacks

Tags: javascript, cordova

I've got a mobile app written with Cordova.  It saves some data to local storage and, at next startup, tries to read it.

I got the code from here:

https://www.neontribe.co.uk/cordova-file-plugin-examples/

```
function readFromFile(fileName, cb, cbErr) {
    var pathToFile = cordova.file.dataDirectory + fileName;
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(pathToFile, function (fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(function (file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onloadend = function (e) {
                cb(JSON.parse(this.result));
            };

            reader.readAsText(file);
        }, cbErr("oops"));
    }, cbErr("darn"));
}

var cbError = function(){}

var fileData;
readFromFile('somefile.txt', function (data) {
    fileData = data;
},cbError );
```

and its all in my onDeviceReady function.

The problem is, when somefile.txt exists both the success callback (cb) AND the error callback (cbError) get executed.  First the cbError and then cb AND cb returns the data I expect.

Both callbacks are getting triggered from fileEntry.file()

Does anyone have a guess as to what's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you coded you are actually invoking the function `cbErr`, not passing it as an argument. Look

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(pathToFile, function (fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(function (file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function (e) {
            cb(JSON.parse(this.result));
        };

        reader.readAsText(file);
    }, cbErr("oops")); // <- This is going to be invoked
}, cbErr("darn"));  // <- This is going to be invoked
```

What you want to do is this

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(pathToFile, function (fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(function (file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function (e) {
            cb(JSON.parse(this.result));
        };

        reader.readAsText(file);
    }, function() { // <- This is going to be sent as an argument
        cbErr("oops")
    });
}, function() { // <- This is going to be sent as an argument
    cbErr("darn")
});
```

In the link that you posted the guy is using the function `.bind`. This is a very interesting function that you use when you want to call a function and return another function, loaded with the scope and arguments that were provided. Look the [mozilla documentation about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).
If you want to follow that example then you should replace your code with the following:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(pathToFile, function (fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(function (file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function (e) {
            cb(JSON.parse(this.result));
        };

        reader.readAsText(file);
    }, cbErr.bind(null, "oops")); // <- Here is the .bind function
}, cbErr.bind(null, "darn")); // <- Here is the .bind function
```

Comment: Thank you.  I tried it and it worked.  But I don't understand why invoking  the callbacks the incorrect thing to do?  I thought, put the function in a variable, pass it to the appropriate place and all it.  What am I missing?

Comment: I'm glad I helped :) As I said, you were invoking the function and the return was being used as a callback, which was undefined. When you first start dealing with callbacks it is a little bit complicated but at the end it is just sending a function as an argument to another function.